# Why do the compiler puts nops seemingly without any reason?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gnu-assembler, no-op

I was playing some code at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/), trying to understand how the compiler outputs the assembly instructions. But while playing, i observed there are certain `nop`s in the assembly instructions produced by the compiler.

### Souce File:

```c
char str[] = "Hello World";

void foo() { 
    for(char i = 0; i < (char)11; i++) {
        if(str[i] == 'o') {
            str[i] = 'a';
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
str:
        .string "Hello World"
foo:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movb    $0, -1(%rbp)
        jmp     .L2
.L4:
        movsbl  -1(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movzbl  str(%rax), %eax
        cmpb    $111, %al
        jne     .L3
        movsbl  -1(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movb    $97, str(%rax)
.L3:
        movzbl  -1(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $1, %eax
        movb    %al, -1(%rbp)
.L2:
        cmpb    $10, -1(%rbp)
        jle     .L4
        nop
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

As you can see at line 24 and 25, there are 2 `nop` instructions. I could not find any reason for these `nop`s to be in there. I believe it has something to do with some timings, but it is not obvious to me... or maybe I am completely wrong. What am I missing?

Note: I am using x86-64 gcc 13.2

Comment: Are you building with or without optimizations enabled? Please [edit] your question to show us the full and complete command you use to build.

Comment: The short answer is: jump/return prediction and possibly shadow stacks. It's faster to have jump locations and targets at certain places. For details read all the answers linked at the top.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not using a normal setup, I have a windows pc where I mostly use MSVC, and do not have GCC installed. For information, I am using default godbolt.org configuration which don't give much information about the build commands.

Comment: That code you show isn't the same as on the compiler explorer. Besides the need to make questions self-contained, also make sure you give us the correct links.

Comment: As for the compiler explorer and the compiler arguments, if you don't pass any arguments then CE will not add any. So if you don't add the `-O` option (to do some optimization, works with all of the big three compilers IIRC) then there will be no optimization. But as mentioned in the linked questions, this might not be the issue. Only way to know for sure is to build with optimization and check (which might actually add *more* nops).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow ehem... no?  That.s not what any of the linked duplicates say.  Please don't make up false explanations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: While some debuggers may benefit from having NOPs as places to set breakpoints, one shouldn't need an "optimizer" to remove NOPs that would have no reason to be generated in the first place.  Some direct-to-binary compilers might produce NOPs in cases where space is reserved for a forward jump that may use an 8-bit or 16-bit displacement, and only the 8-bit displacement turns out to be required, but for a compiler generating assembly code that would not be an issue.